# Flex 3: way to measure how far the mouse has moved since click/hold has started?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I have a canvas with an icon in the upper right hand corner.
What I would like is this:

- the user clicks the icon
- user holds down their mouse button
- user slides the mouse left/right in order to move the canvas the same direction.

Here's the thing that's stumping me... I don't want the canvas to move until the mouse has traveled a certain distance (in pixels).  Then, once the mouse has passed that many pixels, the projects needs to move the same amount of pixels.

Is there a way to find how many pixels the mouse has moved since the mouse was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MOUSE_DOWN MouseEvent get mouseX on MOUSE_MOVE MouseEvent get mouseX compair the two values and you have your answer.
Make sure you up date the old mouseX with the new mouseX if the compaired value is greater then the amount you want.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure either if you want to know the absolute difference in position while doing a drag and drop or you want to record the distance travelled by the mouse.

You need to first react to the mouse down event of the component which triggers the required behavior (your icon) and add listeners to the stage to be notified of mouse movements and a mouse release. On a mouse release, remove the listeners.

Simple example (flex 3)

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var originalX:int;
        private var originalY:int;

        private var diffX:int;
        private var diffY:int;

        private function onBoxClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            originalX = e.stageX;
            originalY = e.stageY;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoved);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDragComplete);
        }

        private function onMouseMoved(e:MouseEvent):void
        {

            diffX = e.stageX > originalX ? e.stageX - originalX 
                                         : originalX - e.stageX;

            diffY = e.stageY > originalY ? e.stageY - originalY 
                                         : originalY - e.stageY;

            trace('Mouse moved, cursor has travelled (x:' + diffX + ', y:' + diffY + ')');
        }

        private function onDragComplete(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace('Mouse released, cursor has travelled (x:' + diffX + ', y:' + diffY + ')');
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoved);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDragComplete);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

One of the problem in this solution is that it does not care about the direction in which the mouse has travelled, which may cause some issues for you but you will figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

At every mouse move event, you look at the mouseX and mouseY coordinates. If it's moved the amount you want, you call a function that moves your icon. Am I missing something here? It should not be too difficult, I think.

Just record the old mouse coordinates (you can do that when the mouse click event is thrown), measure the new mouse coordinates when it's moved the amount you want, then subtract the values and take the absolute value.

Comment: How do i continuously check the mouse's coordinates to see when it's moved a certain distance?

Comment: I don't think you can. I think you have to check every MouseMove event and check the mouse coordinates each time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I quite understood you but maybe you want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               mouseUp="removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, foo)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function foo(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
//              if(mouseX == someNumber)... do what you got to do!!!
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button mouseDown="addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, foo)"/> //Button icon what ever
```

I am pretty sure you can do similar in Flex 3, too.